# SUM y COUNT de registros existentes o no en tablas relacionadas

Tags: mysql

Tengo 3 tablas. 
La primera se llama Meses y esta conformada de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La segunda tabla se llama pedidos y esta conformada asi: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde los campos que estan en el cuadro rojo son los que importan.
La tercera tabla se llama tratamientos y esta conformada asi: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito hacer es primero tomar los meses de la tabla meses, contar los pedidos por mes de la tabla pedidos referidos del campo fecha_reg y luego tomar los valores de la tabla tratamientos, segun el id del campo tratamiento de la tabla pedidos para obtener la suma total por mes.
Actualmente puedo obtener la cantidad de pedidos por mes, pero no asi la suma de los valores por mes. He tratado de todas las formas que se me han ocurrido y encontrado en los diferentes foros, pero no me funciona.
Lo que tengo actualmente es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT YEAR(pedidos.fecha_pedido) AS ANO, nombre_mes, ifnull(count(pedidos.id),0) AS cantidad,

(SELECT SUM(tratamientos.valor) FROM tratamientos INNER JOIN pedidos P ON P.lab = 4 INNER JOIN tratamientos t ON t.id = P.tratamiento) AS TOTAL

FROM meses 

LEFT JOIN pedidos ON meses.id = MONTH(pedidos.fecha_pedido) AND YEAR(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 2018 

GROUP BY meses.id
```

Lo que hice fue tratar de unir las tablas de alguna forma y lo que obtengo es lo siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde claramente, la columna total esta mal y es ahi en donde necesito listar la suma de los valores de los pedidos realizados y mostrar cero en donde la cantidad sea cero.
Si falta codigo o explicar algo, con gusto lo agregare o explicare.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda u orientacion que puedan darme. desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez algo así te sirva. Quite la consulta correlacionada porque no le vi mucho sentido. Cambié `IFNULL` por `COALESCE` (preferencia personal) y los filtros de la consulta correlacionada los puse en una sub consulta a la que se le aplicará el `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    YEAR(a.fecha_pedido) AS 'anio',
    COALESCE(COUNT(a.id_pedido), 0) as 'cantidad',
    meses.nombre_mes,
    COALESCE(SUM(a.valor), 0) as 'total'
FROM 
    meses
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            pedidos.id as 'id_pedido',
            pedidos.fecha_pedido,
            tratamientos.valor,
            pedidos.lab
        FROM 
            pedidos 
            JOIN tratamientos
                ON tratamientos.id = pedidos.tratamiento
        WHERE 
            pedidos.lab = 4
            AND YEAR(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 2018
    ) a 
        ON meses.id = MONTH(a.fecha_pedido)
GROUP BY meses.id;
```

Al correr esta consulta en varias tablas con datos de prueba, arrojó un resultado de la forma.

```
+------+------------+----------+-------+
| anio | nombre_mes | cantidad | total |
+------+------------+----------+-------+
| 2018 | Enero      |        5 | 20000 |
| 2018 | Febrero    |        4 | 16000 |
| 2018 | Marzo      |        5 | 20000 |
| 2018 | Abril      |        1 |  4000 |
| NULL | Mayo       |        0 |     0 |
| NULL | Junio      |        0 |     0 |
| NULL | Julio      |        0 |     0 |
| NULL | Agosto     |        0 |     0 |
| NULL | Septiembre |        0 |     0 |
| NULL | Octubre    |        0 |     0 |
| 2018 | Noviembre  |        2 |  8000 |
| NULL | Diciembre  |        0 |     0 |
+------+------------+----------+-------+
```

Lo pensé algo así:

```
SELECT
    -- donde operas con los datos
    -- de la tabla principal y donde se
    -- maneja la presentación de los datos.
FROM 
    etc
    LEFT JOIN (
        -- tabla principal que funcionará para servirse
        -- de sus datos.
    ) etc
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias estimado.. funciono a la primera. no sabes como te lo agradezco. no sabes como te lo agradezco. muchas gracias por tu tiempo .. saludos.